# The Stack Exchange app showed 1 Jan 1970 as question date, is this a known bug?

Tags: bug, android-app

When opening a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601967/how-to-let-the-icon-scale-with-a-qtpushbutton) at Stack Overflow, the Stack Exchange app showed 1 Jan 1970 as question date:

> [image: 1970 screenshot]

But when reopening [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601967/how-to-let-the-icon-scale-with-a-qtpushbutton), it was fixed:

> [image: no 1970]

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: It's either SE API problem (jumbled data), network problem (timeout, incomplete data), or SE app problem (failed parsing). Just in case it's SE app problem, what is the version you're currently using? (You can check on Menu - About). **Edit:** considering that the question had been asked for 6 minutes at that time, probably there's a data discrepancy between SE API and SE server?

Comment: Jan 1, 1970 is also the Unix epoch. Coincidence? I think not...

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN of course it's not "Coincidence", it just means the API returned null, or failure in parsing caused a fallback to default value, as Andrew said. As a side note, are you aware it's now really hard to ping you? Your name does not begin with unicode so one has to guess it "begins" with a "u" letter. (which is flipped.)